# Does Salesforce publish their SOQL and SOSL grammar?

Tags: soql, sosl

Does Salesforce publish their SOQL and SOSL grammar? Do we have any link to download?

I need to use ANTLR for creating parser on the SOQL and SOSL grammar.
Please can any one help on this.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce used to publish the grammar in BNF (Backus-Naur Form), but have been using a less formal representation for a number of releases now.

It's hiding in the documentation, specifically [SOQL SELECT Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm)

> SELECT *fieldList* [subquery][...]
>   [TYPEOF typeOfField whenExpression[...] elseExpression END][...]
>   FROM objectType[,...]
>       [USING SCOPE filterScope]
>   [WHERE conditionExpression]
>   [WITH [DATA CATEGORY] filteringExpression]
>   [GROUP BY {fieldGroupByList|ROLLUP (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)|CUBE (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)}
>       [HAVING havingConditionExpression] ]
>   [ORDER BY fieldOrderByList {ASC|DESC} [NULLS {FIRST|LAST}] ]
>   [LIMIT numberOfRowsToReturn]
>   [OFFSET numberOfRowsToSkip]
>   [FOR {VIEW  | REFERENCE}[,...] ]
>        [ UPDATE {TRACKING|VIEWSTAT}[,...] ]

and [SOSL Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm).

> FIND {SearchQuery}
>   [ IN SearchGroup ]
>   [ RETURNING FieldSpec [[ toLabel(fields)] [convertCurrency(*Amount*)] [FORMAT()]] ]
>   [ WITH DivisionFilter ]
>   [ WITH DATA CATEGORY DataCategorySpec ]
>   [ WITH SNIPPET[(target_length=n)] ]
>   [ WITH NETWORK NetworkIdSpec ]
>   [ WITH PricebookId ]
>   [ WITH METADATA ]
>   [ LIMIT n ]
>
> [ UPDATE [TRACKING], [VIEWSTAT] ]

They use notation described in [Typographical Conventions Used in this Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_typos.htm).

It'd take some effort, but I'm sure you could convert those documentation pages into a BNF grammar.

Googling for your question turns up a few (albeit outdated) resources as well:
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/09/23/syntax-rules-for-soql/

and
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_api.pdf?major=146 (with the BNF grammar for SOQL on page 66)

Answer (score 2):

Mulesoft has published their [antlr3](https://github.com/mulesoft/salesforce-soql-parser/blob/master/src/main/antlr3/org/mule/tools/soql/parser/SOQL.g) & [antlr4](https://github.com/mulesoft/salesforce-soql-parser/blob/antlr4/SOQL.g4) grammars.  I was able to generate and run classes using the antlr4 grammar & so far, it seems to be complete.

Comment: Updated my answer because I was totally wrong about the grammar having unsupported rules. I just didn't realize you could do this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm